# Table width doesn't size correctly to % of container

Tags: html

I'm having trouble trying to use tables as cells ( for responsiveness ) in my code.

I have 2 pieces of code, the first one (the expected behavior I'm looking) is a table of 637px with 2 tds splitting the size with %, the size splits correctly, one cell gets 319px, and the other one 318px.

```
<table style="width: 637px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50.07849293563579%">THIS IS 319</td>
            <td width="49.92150706436421%">THIS IS 318</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The second (what my code looks like) is a main table with a td with 2 tables inside with float left and the same exact width used on the case 1. In this case table 1 is 318px, and table 2 is 318px. missing 1 pixel. where did it go? Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="637px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; width: 50.07849293563579%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>THIS IS 318</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; width: 49.92150706436421%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>THIS IS 318</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do both tables have the same exact CSS? There's a ton of CSS things that could cause a 1px difference and it might not even come from the table. First thing I would do is switch the `width` attribute on the 2nd table to the CSS `width` declaration like on the first table and see if that changes anything.

Comment: already did, no CSS classes hit anything, and tried width either trough CSS and ATTR. you can feel free to try code and see the behaviour

Comment: Rounding error ....